# How much shorter is the turkey's cooking time if I increase the temperature?

Tags: baking, oven, turkey

I'm baking a turkey in a bag, the brown grocery store type of bag. I love this recipe but I don't have time to cook it at the specified temperature. If my recipe says I should cook my 9 pound turkey at 325 for 4 1/2 hours, how long should I cook it at 350 in a regular/conventional propane oven?

Comment: Changing the temperature is not advisable for such large items. The temperature in the core of the turkey needs to become high enough... burning the outside won't get the inside to the proper temperature much faster. A higher temperature oven will increase the differential between the core temp and the exterior, leading to a drier turkey.

Comment: I know this is not the answer you are looking for, so I post it as a comment. You should cook it to 60°C as shown by a roast thermometer stuck in the middle, no matter how long it takes or how much the turkey weighs. As @MyrddinEmrys mentioned, in theory you can cook at a higher temperature and the rule stil holds, but then you end up with a dried out turkey.

Comment: @rumtscho: Only 60°C/140°F? USDA recommends 74°C/165°F for turkey. The time & temperature tables say you'd need over a half hour at 140°F (depending on fat %).

Comment: What if I decrease my heating/cooking temperate? http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/64779/how-to-adjust-time-for-oven-stuck-at-350f

Answer (score 1):

You can typically roast a turkey anywhere between 325 and 375, so 350 should not be an issue. [AllRecipes](http://allrecipes.com/howto/turkey-cooking-time-guide/) provides cooking times for an oven set at 350. Note that a stuffed turkey will take longer to cook.

4 1/2 hours is longer than than most [references](http://www.fsis.usda.gov/Factsheets/Lets_Talk_Turkey/index.asp) indicate for a 9 pound turkey at 325.  If you have successfully made this recipe in the oven you are planning to use, you may want to budget in an extra 30-60 minutes.

I have found that the easiest way to keep track of the the status of the poultry is to place a [leave-in meat](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002U1RNIO) thermometer into a thigh (but not next to the bone). The thermometer probe will stay in the meat and measure the internal temperature as it cooks.  The turkey is done when the internal temperature of the thigh reaches 160 (FDA recommends 165) and the juices are clear when slicing the thigh.

Comment: If you pull the turkey out of the oven and tent it at 160, carry-over cooking will easily get you to 165.