# How to adjust time for oven stuck at 350F

Tags: oven, cooking-time, turkey, gas, lasagna

My oven is stuck at 350F. I need to cook a lasagna that requires 400F for `1:55` (one hour 55 minutes). I also need to cook a turkey at 375F for `4:30` (separately). How do I adjust since my oven is stuck at 350F?

The two means are back to back, not together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turkey and lasagna are both fine at 350F (177C). For turkey, here's a guide at 350F.

From [AllRecipes:](http://dish.allrecipes.com/turkey-cooking-time-guide/)

[image]

[image]

Take the turkey out to rest when the thickest part of the thigh registers 160F (71C). Carry over will bring it to 165F (74C). (Picture from [Fine Cooking](http://www.finecooking.com/item/12583/you-want-me-to-stick-it-where))

Your lasagna will be fine too, it just needs to cook a bit longer at 350F. Consider it done when it registers about 160F (71C)

You may get a bit less browning than is ideal. If you can use your broiler for a few minutes, either of your dishes may benefit from that.

Comment: Ok, that turkey question is yours! ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The turkey is going to be quite happy with the slightly lower temp - you will need a bit more time, but I'd guestimate 1/2 hour tops should be ok. This is another occasion to repeat our all important:

> Use a thermomenter to determine doneness of your roast, not a timer!

The lasagna shouldn't be a problem either - I'm surprised at the long baking time anyway. Again, perhaps another 1/2 hour should be sufficient, if necessary at all.

Just note that at 350F / 175C your dishes might be browning a little less that you'd expect at 400F / 205C. Consider using the broiler when they are almost done to crisp them up a bit.